# How to trigger an event to pass a list of items through react event

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have the following React-Select dropdown:

```
 <Select isMulti placeholder="Select Option" options={soptions}   
                         
                         onChange={this.selectValue(this)}/>
```

As the dropdown is a multi drop-down,I want to pass multiple values to the select handler but all at once instead of triggering the event when each value is selected.
What event could I trigger or are there any other methods?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to handle different select values with different functions? Why not do it like this: `onChange={(v) => { if (v === something) {...} else if () {...} ... }}`?

Comment: @ŁukaszKarczewski I want to pass all the values to a single function which then passes them to a url. The conditioning doesn't work in my case because the values are dynamically generated and keeps changing all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below function should do the trick. If you want all the values in an array.

```
 <Select isMulti options={this.options} onChange={this.handleChange} /> 
  
 handleChange=(e)=>{
    const value = Array.isArray(e) ? e.map(s => s.value) : []
    console.log(value)
  }
```